# (Python) How to combine two program

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt

I'd like to combine two programs. I want to use 'second code' in 'first code'.
I have tried many ways but all of them fail.

For reference, showing always on top is programmed by ChristopheD.

-----------------------------------my program--------------------------------------------

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import os, time, MySQLdb, socket, sys



student_number = ''
t=''
t_m=''
t_day=''
t_hour=''
t_min=''
t_year=''
current_time=''



try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)





class Ui_Dialog(object):


    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(1680, 1050)
        Dialog.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        Dialog.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(1270, 830, 181, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Agency FB"))
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 440, 81, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Agency FB"))
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(700, 440, 191, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Agency FB"))
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 550, 151, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Agency FB"))
        font.setPointSize(28)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtGui.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(700, 550, 191, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Agency FB"))
        font.setPointSize(26)
        self.lineEdit_2.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit_2"))
        self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(450, 190, 651, 71))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Agency FB"))
        font.setPointSize(32)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_3"))
        self.label_4 = QtGui.QLabel(Dialog)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 900, 211, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Calibri"))
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_4"))


        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)



        buttonLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        Dialog.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.clickbutton)


        #self.btnExit.clicked.connect(self.close)
        #self.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.close)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "사용시작", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "학번", None))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "비밀번호", None))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "<html><head/><body><p><span style=\" color:#ff0000;\">아래 정보를 반드시 입력해주세요</span></p></body></html>", None))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Developed by Two PJH", None))


    def clickbutton(self):
        global student_number
        student_number = unicode(self.lineEdit.text())
        self.final()
        self.lineEdit.clear() #학번 지우기
        self.lineEdit_2.clear() #비번 지우기
        Dialog.close() #시작화면 닫고
        Dialog2.show() #종료창 열고



    def final(self):
        #global지정--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        global t, t_m, t_day, t_hour, t_min, t_year, current_time

        #컴퓨터 이름--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        computer_name = os.environ['USERNAME'] #컴퓨터에 저장된 컴퓨터이름 불러오기
        #현재 시간 받기------------------------------------------------------------------------
        t=time.localtime()
        t_m=str(t.tm_mon)
        t_day=str(t.tm_mday)
        t_hour=str(t.tm_hour)
        t_min=str(t.tm_min)
        t_year=str(t.tm_year)
        current_time=t_year+ '/' +t_m + '/' + t_day + '_' + t_hour + ':' + t_min
        #DB연동-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        db = MySQLdb.connect(host = '203.241.227.100',  user='root', passwd='bment', charset='euckr' ,db='admin' ) #mysql 서버 접속
        cur = db.cursor() #커서를 생성하여 sql 코드 사용
        z=(computer_name, student_number, current_time) #필드별 넣을 변수 리스트화
        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO a1 VALUES(%s,%s,%s);""", z) #DB로 값 보내기
        cur.close() #생성해놓은 커서를 종료해 내용 저장
        #출력---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        print 'Your Computer Computer_name is : %s' %computer_name #컴퓨터이름 출력
        print 'Your Computer student_number is : %s' %student_number #학번 출력
        print 'Your Computer Time is : %s' %current_time #시간 출력






class Ui_Dialog2(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog2):
        Dialog2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog2.resize(120, 50)
        Dialog2.move(1530,910)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog2)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 120, 50))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog2)

        buttonLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        Dialog2.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.clickbutton)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog2):
        Dialog2.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "End", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "종료", None))
        self.pushButton.setAutoDefault(False)

    def clickbutton(self):
        self.final2()
        Dialog2.close()
        Dialog.show()


    def final2(self):
        #global지정--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        #global t, t_m, t_day, t_hour, t_min, t_year, current_time
        #컴퓨터 이름--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        computer_name = os.environ['USERNAME'] #컴퓨터에 저장된 컴퓨터이름 불러오기
        #현재 시간 받기------------------------------------------------------------------------
        t2=time.localtime()
        t2_m=str(t2.tm_mon)
        t2_day=str(t2.tm_mday)
        t2_hour=str(t2.tm_hour)
        t2_min=str(t2.tm_min)
        t2_year=str(t2.tm_year)
        close_time=t2_year+ '/' +t2_m + '/' + t2_day + '_' + t2_hour + ':' + t2_min
        #DB연동-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        db = MySQLdb.connect(host = '203.241.227.100',  user='root', passwd='bment', charset='euckr' ,db='admin' ) #mysql 서버 접속
        cur = db.cursor() #커서를 생성하여 sql 코드 사용
        z=(computer_name, student_number, current_time, close_time) #필드별 넣을 변수 리스트화
        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO a2 VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s);""", z) #DB로 값 보내기
        cur.close() #생성해놓은 커서를 종료해 내용 저장
        #출력---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        print 'Your Computer Computer_name is : %s' %computer_name #컴퓨터이름 출력
        print 'Your Computer student_number is : %s' %student_number #학번 출력
        print 'Your Computer Time is : %s' %current_time #시간 출력
        print 'Your Computer Close Time is : %s' %close_time #시간 출력





if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    Dialog2 = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    ui2 = Ui_Dialog2()
    ui2.setupUi(Dialog2)

    palette = QtGui.QPalette()

    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Background,QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QImage("background8877.jpg")))
    Dialog.setPalette(palette)

    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---------------------------------programed by ChristopheD----------------------------------

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class mymainwindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, None, QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
mywindow = mymainwindow()
mywindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: I think this question is really badly posed. It is absolutely not clear what exactly is meant by combining two programmes or where the actual problem in this special case is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(If program 2 is `QMainWindow`) Your can put widget from program 1 to program 2 by set set central widget from program 2.

Example;

```
class mymainwindow(QtGui.QMainWindow): # <- from program 2
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, None, QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        .
        .
        myQDialog = QtGui.QDialog() # <- from program 1
        ui = Ui_Dialog()            # <- from program 1
        ui.setupUi(myQDialog)       # <- from program 1
        .
        .
        self.setCentralWidget(myQDialog) # <- from program 1 into 2
        .
        .
```

**Reference** : http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget

---

But, If program 2 is `QWidget`, Your can set it by set layout.

---

**LAST EDITED 20 / 8 / 2014 8 : 37** Please read document to understand difference `QMainWindow` & `QDialog`.

**`QMainWindow`** : http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qmainwindow.html

**`QDialog`** : http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdialog.html

---

Regards,

Comment: Very very thank you. but I want to use 'second code' in 'first code' one more analysis plz..

Comment: A-re???? (Are your kidding me ?) Your want to put 'QtGui.QMainWindow' into 'QtGui.QDialog' ? It's impossible (But actually it can but NOT recommend for more infomation please read document reference class). an why your comment just (really) like this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398528/pyqt4-i-want-to-use-keyboard-shortcuts-in-my-code/25398714?noredirect=1#comment39620201_25398714